# how can a html table have misaligned cell borders

Tags: html, css-tables, nested-table

I am struggling to make a html table that copies the layout of the table above.
I am just wondering what techniques to use and to recreate that table

I have tried nested tables and have looked into using div instead to create this but am still having issues, mainly with the way that the lines are presented in this and are not in an obvious layout

[image: relevant image]

Comment: colspan/rowspan and/or multiple nested tables

Comment: I would have shown it to you, but I have no desire to rewrite all the texts of this "table". And I don't believe that we can do without having them because they are essential to verify the correctness of the boxes. Otherwise, don't believe that your design uses only 1 `<table>`, it uses several, and also some `<DIV>`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cool tool:

https://tabletag.net/

Here you need to nest a table in the second row

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #595959;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
}

th {
  background: #f0e6cc;
}

.even {
  background: #fbf8f0;
}

.odd {
  background: #fefcf9;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td colspan="5"></td>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td colspan="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6"></td>
      <td colspan="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]